# Cisco AM10 USB wireless adapter not recognized on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, drivers, usb, cisco

I recently updated (and also tried a fresh install) of the most recent Ubuntu OS for my Dell Optiplex.  My USB adapter worked fine before the update.  Now the adapter is not working / recognized.  What has changed with the update?  Do I need to install a driver? If so, can u give me some hints on how to do it (sorry, I'm a newb to Linux)?